# iOS Rxswift handle CancelButton click in searchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, rx-swift, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with IOS Rxswift. The problem is with `CancelButtonClick` from `UISearchBar`. whenever `Cancel` is clicked the `searchbar.text` is immediately set to existing `text` and fire event `textDidEndEditing` which trigger a search (my search trigger condition is combine of `searchbar.text` and `textDidEndEditing`.

I have tried to set `searchbar.text = ""` when `Cancel` is clicked but seem `searchbar.text` is set to existing text and fire `textDidEndEditing` before any further action. Anyway to handle the Cancel button? I just want to disable any action whenever `Cancel` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is exactly how the search bar delegate works. Instead of making your network request when `textDidEndEditing` fires, connect it to `searchButtonClicked`.

Comment: Thanks. connect to searchButtonClicked and all done. is there a way to artificially stimulate searchbuttonclicked?

Comment: Even if there was a way, you shouldn't do it. Don't treat your view like a model.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow the pattern. Can help me take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803206/ios-rxswift-use-kingfisher-to-prefetch-cell-image