# IOS Rxswift use Kingfisher to prefetch cell Image

Tags: rx-swift, prefetch, kingfisher

I'm trying to implement `Kingfisher` prefetch feature inside an Rxswift project. The problem is with these 2 function

```
collectionView.rx.prefetchItems
collectionView.rx.cancelPrefetchingForItems
```

The instruction at `Kingfisher` `github` is quite short

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.prefetchDataSource = self
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        let urls = indexPaths.flatMap { URL(string: $0.urlString) }
        ImagePrefetcher(urls: urls).start()
    }
}
```

How can we implement with Rxswift? anyway to get the `models` and then the `urls` of `models` from array of `indexpath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will walk you thru how I figured out the solution to help you figure out future solutions...

I'm assuming that the struct that holds the URL strings is called `Item` and that you have an `Observable<[Item]>` that you are currently using to load up the collection view. I'm also assuming that you only have one section in your collection.

First, we know that something needs to happen when the `prefetchItemsAt` sends an event so we start with that:

```
let foo = collectionView.rx.prefetchItems
```

Now inspect the type of `foo` to see that it is a `ControlEvent<[IndexPath]>`. A ControlEvent is a kind of observable. We just need the `items` part of the IndexPaths, so lets `map` that:

```
let foo = collectionView.rx.prefetchItems
    .map { $0.map { $0.item } }
```

(The double map is an unfortunate consequence of Swift not supporting higher kinded types) Now inspect the type of `foo`. It is an Observable array of ints. Those ints are indexes into our items array. So we need access to the most recently emitted items:

```
    (as above)
    .withLatestFrom(items) { indexes, elements in
        indexes.map { elements[$0] }
    }
```

So `withLatestFrom` is like `combineLatest` except it only fires when the primary observable emits a value, not when the secondary observable does.

Now, inspecting the type of `foo` will find that it's an Observable array of Items. The exact items who's urls' we want to send to the ImagePrefetcher. So we need to extract the urlStrings into URLs.

```
    (as above)
    .map { $0.compactMap { URL(string: $0.urlString) } }
```

And with that, we have the array of URLs we want ImagePrefetcher to consume. Since it consumes data, it needs to be wrapped it in a subscribe block.

```
    (as above)
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        ImagePrefetcher(urls: $0).start()
    })
```

At this point, `foo` is a disposable so it just needs to be collected in our dispose bag... Here is the entire block of code.

```
collectionView.rx.prefetchItems
    .map { $0.map { $0.item } }
    .withLatestFrom(items) { indexes, elements in
        indexes.map { elements[$0] }
    }
    .map { $0.compactMap { URL(string: $0.urlString) } }
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        ImagePrefetcher(urls: $0).start()
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

One last bit to make everything clean... Everything between `prefetchItems` and the `subscribe` can be moved into the ViewModel if you have one.

The key takeaway here is that you can use the types to guide you, and you need to know what operators are available to manipulate Observables which you can find at http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Comment: First of all. Thanks for your detail explanation. I manage to follow your instruction and make it works. But how do we test whether our implementation actually works?

Comment: Once you move the code into your view model, you can test it by emitting values into the inputs and inspecting the value that gets emitted by the output.

Comment: Do we need confrom and set delegate our viewcontroller to UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching ? i put break point at End of subscribe but seem never be called (btw i should we change to driver bfore first map?)

Comment: No, don't set the prefetch delegate and don't assign anything to the collectionView's delegate. Rx takes care of all that. If you want to use Driver, change to it at the very last moment, just before the subscribe.

Comment: I have implemented complete code here: https://pastebin.com/berJnTdL. But seem there is no sign of it working (print statement never execute). the code is put in viewdidload()

Comment: It could be that `viewModel.results` hasn't fired yet when prefetch is fires. Put a `debug` on `viewModel.results` and another immediately after `prefetchItems` and see which emits first. If `prefetchItems` emits first, then reverse them. Let me know and I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Hi i put a breakpoint after prefetchItems and see it only triggered 1 time when view is loaded. After that there is no trigger when scrolling down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181842/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-le-khanh-vinh).